# Extract Emoji in JSON and extract it out

Tags: python, emoji

I have a Json file and i need to extract the emoji. How can i do that?

```
filename = raw_input("Enter the JSON filename: ")
        fp = open(filename)
        jobj = json.load(fp)
        break
      except:
        print("File is not valid. Try again.")
```

Comment: *i need to extract the emoji* well that largely depends upon the structure of your JSON object. You may start with `import json;json.loads(fp.read())`

Answer (score 0):

*i don't know what your json data looks like but give a try like this if possible share your json data*

```
import json
filename = raw_input("Enter the JSON filename: ")
        fp = open(filename)
        jobj = json.loads(fp.read())
        emoji = jobj["emojitext"]
        break
      except:
        print("File is not valid. Try again.")
```